# Change UID and GID in alpine docker container

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I want to change an alpine-based container user's UID and GID.

But there's no `usermod` and `groupmod`. Are there equivalents?

(This is for a running container, not an image.)

Comment: You seem to be asking about cli tooling while the container is running, but you can set the uid when you start the container `docker run --user user:group`

Comment: @ChrisBecke Thanks. The image is used in a docker compose file, and the upstream Dockerfile [hardcodes](https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/blob/c0fc53e22602fc4b3c8d890d235d0911bef074fe/Dockerfile#L45-L51) those values. Do you think it's possible for me to get around that somehow?

Comment: `user: uid:gid` is a compose service attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `docker run` command can be passed a user and group (or uid / gid).

`docker run --user 2000:2000 acme`

Or, via compose, the `user:` attribute can be used.

`compose.yml`

```yaml
services:
  acme:
    image: my-alpine:latest
    user: 2000:2000
```

In the case that ids are used, neither the user id or group id needs to exist in the container.

Comment: Thanks. This is the important bit: "Assuming the group and user exist before the container is created". If that is the case, this is the perfect answer. Sadly in my case I still need to change the uid/gid as I noted in my answer. This is probably more robust for more use cases; but it has to be coupled with a custom Dockerfile where one adds the user and group beforehand, then in the compose file one can select them. BTW I didn't know about `user` I see they added it for the modern [compose format](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#user), very nice!

Comment: I don't think there's a requirement that the user or group exist; you can use these options to specify numeric user and group IDs even if the user isn't listed in the container `/etc/passwd`.

Answer (score 2):

This is my workaround (must be put in an entrypoint script):

```
$ id bob
uid=1000(bob) gid=1000(bob) groups=1000(bob),1000(bob)

$ apk --no-cache add shadow                              # <-----
$ groupmod --gid 2000 bob
$ usermod --uid 2000 --gid 2000 bob
$ apk del shadow

$ id bob
uid=2000(bob) gid=2000(bob) groups=2000(bob),2000(bob)
```

Please let me know if there's a way to do this without installing anything.