# Gitlab runner in docker - Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://dind:2375

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ce

I know this could be taken as a duplicate but I have tried everything I have found on the internet with no success.

I'm trying to set up a local gitlab-ce server on Windows using the Docker Desktop, but I'm not experienced enough to solve this error. I'm probably not understanding the situation very well.

I installed gitlab runner and registered it via Docker Compose. Here's the file:

```yaml
services:
  dind:
    container_name: dind
    image: docker:25.0.3-dind
    restart: unless-stopped
    privileged: true
    environment:
      DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
    command:
      - --storage-driver=overlay2
    networks:
      - playground
    volumes:
      - D:/Playground/data/gitlab-runner/dind:/var/lib/docker

  runner:
    container_name: runner
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine-v16.9.0
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - DOCKER_HOST=tcp://dind:2375
    networks:
      - playground
    volumes:
      - D:/Playground/conf/gitlab-runner:/etc/gitlab-runner:z

  register-runner:
    container_name: registerrunner
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine-v16.9.0
    restart: 'no'
    depends_on:
      - dind
    environment:
      - CI_SERVER_URL=http://gitlab.playground.local/
      - RUNNER_TOKEN=...
    command:
      - register
      - --non-interactive
      - --url=http://gitlab.playground.local/
      - --token=...
      - --name=Runner
      - --executor=docker
      - --docker-image=docker:25.0.3-dind
      - --docker-volumes=/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - playground
    volumes:
      - D:/Playground/conf/gitlab-runner:/etc/gitlab-runner:z
      - D:/Playground/data/gitlab-runner/dind:/var/lib/docker
networks:
  playground:
    name: playground
    driver: bridge
```

And my config.toml:

```toml
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
log_level = "debug"
log_format = "text"
connection_max_age = "15m0s"
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "Runner"
  url = "http://gitlab.playground.local/"
  id = 34
  token = "..."
  token_obtained_at = 2024-02-22T03:30:08Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
  [runners.docker]
    host = "tcp://dind:2375"
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:25.0.3-dind"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
    cache_dir = "cache"
    shm_size = 0
    network_mtu = 0
```

The `http://gitlab.playground.local` is conveniently defined in the Windows host file and I can access the instance. The problem is with the runner.

I can see the active runner in my gitlab instance, but when I run the pipeline I constantly get the following error:

```
ERROR: Failed to remove network for build
ERROR: Preparation failed: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://dind:2375. Is the docker daemon running? (docker.go:933:12s)
```

I've already exposed the daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS in Docker, as I have seen in other threads with similar problems, but nothing changed.

**Edit:** more info added below

I've basically played a lot of trial and error up to the current setup. Among other things, I already tried not to use Docker-in-Docker and reduce the complexity, but I also got an exception.
I also tried to cover permissions using `usermod -aG docker gitlab-runner`, but alpine doesn't have the `usermod` command, so I added the attribute `user: 2000:2000` in the docker compose file [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76538097/change-uid-and-gid-in-alpine-docker-container), but again without success.

I really believe (it's more of a hope than a certainty) that my configuration is not far from correct, but there is something that escapes me and I don't know what it is.

What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to SO ! If this could be taken as duplicate, add which other soltuions you tried and the results so it won't be marked as duplicated and it will improve teh question.

Comment: Thanks @Skunka! You're right. I have updated the description accordingly.

Comment: I don't think the configuration is quite right. Your `docker:dind` container should be configured in your project CI configuration YAML (`.gitlab-ci.yml`), not the `docker-compose` you're using to deploy your runner. If you want to use the `docker:dind` service, you should also remove the `/var/run/docker.sock` from your volumes mounts in the runner configuration. Review [the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html) carefully, keeping in mind **multiple configuration methods are described in the docs, you must choose only one method**.

Comment: @Sytech wonderful response. You were absolutely right, I misconfigured it but even applying your suggestions, I still get more issues. Finally after several days jumping from error to error I gave up on gitlab and got gitea up and running in just a couple of hours. I appreciate your help though, thanks a lot!